# app hang when click on two buttons at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Problem:** My app hanging when i click on two buttons at the same time.  My buttons are

[Notification center label http://imageshack.com/a/img59/676/ob8s.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img59/676/ob8s.png)

How to solve this problem.There is a way to give priority for these buttons.

Thanks.

Comment: Can we get the code/actions that are attached to these buttons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to limit the touch to one button only, use

```
[myButton setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

Comment: Just a small correction, `setExclusiveTouch:` is setter method for property on **instance** and not a **class** method. Its usage is `[btnObj setExclusiveTouch:YES]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use perform selector with delay. Assume you are calling btnClicked: method for both button click.

```
-(void) btnClicked:(id) btn {

  [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self]
  [self performSelector:@selector(executeOperation:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.05];

}

-(void) executeOperation:(id) btn {

    if(btn == btn1) {
    //operation 1
    }
    else {
    //operation 2
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS should be calling one IBAction method first, then the next.

Add an "actionInProgress" instance variable.

When the user taps a button, check if it's == YES. If it is, ignore the button press. Then go on to handle the button action, and set actionInProgress = FALSE once you're done.

Alternately in each IBAction method you could set the other button's disabled flag to YES, to prevent the second button click.

Comment: can you show some code for these